# How to achieve a switch case block which is scalable?

Tags: java, switch-statement, conditional-statements

While starting to build an application, I stared using a switch case block with only five cases to be considered. Later when the build progressed, more cases came into picture and that started creating problems. I know I might have designed it wrongly at the first place, but if such things come as a change how do I effectively approach this? An example is given below

Starting with this

```
switch case 1: /*do function1()*/ break;
       case 2: /*do function2()*/ break;
```

Later, a 100 cases come in

```
switch case 1: /*do function1()*/ break;
       case 2: /*do function2()*/ break;
       ....
       case 100: /*do function100()*/ break;
```

I am sure that converting these cases into 100 if conditions is not going to be a very good approach, so is there a way this can be done?

Please consider that the functions given in the code above are simple mathematical functions for now.

Comment: you could extract all those blocks to seperate methods with clear and distinctive names.

Comment: Depending on your code, you could maybe use a `Map` to store the functions (with an appropriate Interface).

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks, and by that I would have to manage both the condition and methods, wouldn't I?

Comment: it is your code, so of course you need to manage it. but it'l be a lot easier to read then a few hundred if else if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an interface like this:

```
public interface MyFunction {
    public void compute();
}
```

and a `Map` with the previous interface as values:

```
Map<Integer,MyFunction> myFunctionsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

You need to initialize the map with all of you functions:

```
myFunctionsMap.put(1,new MyFuntion() {
    @Override
    public void compute() {
        /*do function1()*/
    }
});
```

for each of your functions, the syntax might be a bit heavy with anonymous classes, you can implement you functions in separate classes and use them as well.

Now instead of the switch, you simply use the map:

```
myFunctionsMap.get(theValueSwitched).execute();
```

Depending of how you initialize the map, the values of the keys and how you use it, you might want to check `myFunctionsMap.contains(theValueSwitched)` (this would be your default case if you have one).

Edit: Java 8 shorter syntax would be `myFunctionsMap.put(1,() -> {/*do function1()*/});`

Answer (score 1):

You could name your methods something like method1, method2, method3 , etc .. and use reflexion to call them, using you variable. You wouldn't have a lengthy switch, that way.

I have no ideas if that is efficient or not, though.

Here's a neat exemple, from wikipedia's reflection page.

```
Object foo = Class.forName("complete.classpath.and.Foo").newInstance();
// Alternatively: Object foo = Foo.class.newInstance();
Method m = foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hello", new Class<?>[0]);
m.invoke(foo);
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I get what you told. Efficiency is equivalent to how better we write the reflection code then I believe. Let me have a check